# overwrite path to parent in maven module

Tags: maven

For some investigations I have used another pom which calls module poms. Unfortunately from the documentation it looks like properties are only overwritten if that pom is configured for all modules as a parent

Is there a parameter to run a maven module pom with a command that overwrites the relative path to the parent pom ?

Or even better to set that path in a called pom to make it parent for all modules?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you would like to override at runtime and temporarily, via command line, the parent pom of a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible.
The reference of parent pom cannot be parametrized because the parent pom resolution happens before evaluation of the properties (because it is parent pom who can also define properties for your pom).

In order to change a set of properties in your pom, rather than specifying them in a pom you wanted to plug in as a adhoc parent pom, you can create a shell (or windows cmd) script and specify the properties as `-D` parameters of your maven command.
That is

```
mvn clean install -Dthe.property.1.to.override=value1 -Dthe.property.2.to.override=value2 ...
```

You can also specify your properties and values in a property file and let maven load this file by using [Maven Properties Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html).

Comment: Thanks for that Stephan, I was afraid there is no other solution to that. My work is a bit reverse engineering huge orphaned files so I would have liked to inject files with out changing the module poms...